# How to echo element every i ==1th time in a table?

Tags: php, foreach, datatables

**Note** "$db" is an instance of my database class, and "getRows()" is a custom function within that class.

I have a jQuery Datatable, and I need to populate it with data (domain names and MX Records). I need it to print to the table as:

```
domain1 |   MX Record1
        |   MX Record2

domain2 |   MX Record1
        |   MX Record2
        |   MX Record3
```

It is working in plain text with this code:

```
foreach ($records = $db->getRows("select name, group_concat(content) from records where type='MX' group by name", ['']) as $record) {

    $strings = explode(",", $record['group_concat(content)']);
    $name = $record['name'];
    $count = 0;
    foreach($strings as $string => $mx) {
        $count++;
        if($count <= 1 ) {
            echo "<strong>" . $name . "</strong> | " . $mx;
        }
        else {
            echo "----------------------- | " . $mx;
        }
        echo " -- Count: " . $count . "<br>";

    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```

The output is:

```
domain1.com | xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 1
----------- | xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 2
----------  | xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 3

domain2.net | xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.net -- Count: 1
----------- | xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.net -- Count: 2

domain3.com | xxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 1
----------- | xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 2
----------  | xxxx-x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -- Count: 3
```

However, within my table, the output is horrible. Here is the code for everything (minus CSS):

```
<div class="container">
     <table id="mx_report_table" class="table table-bordered" >
          <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>MX Record</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php

          foreach($records = $db->getRows("SELECT name, group_concat(content) FROM records WHERE type='MX' GROUP BY name", ['']) as $record) {
              $strings = explode(",", $record['group_concat(content)']);
              $name = $record['name'];
              $count = 0;


              foreach($strings as $string => $mx) {
                  $count++;
                  if($count <= 1) {
                      echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$mx</td></tr>";
                  }
                  else {
                      echo "<tr><td></td><td>$mx</td></tr>";
                  }

              }
          }
          ?>
          </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    document.title='MX Report';
    $(function() {
        $('#mx_report_table').DataTable({
            "scrollY":"400px",
            "scrollCollapse":true,
            "paging":true,
            "lengthMenu":[10,25,50,100],
            "pageLength":25
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is what the table looks like:

[image]

Where have I gone wrong if I'm basically (at least I think) doing the exact same in my table?

Comment: Not the issue you ask about but highly recommended to do even before: If you output HTML you need to encode the output as HTML. That is especially true for user-data, that is for example the data your query from the database (it counts as user-input). So encode $name and $mx as HTML (e.g. https://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: Allways isolate your problem and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case your PHP is fine (http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fgdp-8mgk), it's the `DataTable`-plugin that's messing up the empty cells (https://jsfiddle.net/bep6uvfo/)

Comment: Does the name correspond to an MX record? ie are they pairs?

Comment: @James Yes, every domain has corresponding mx records. I just want the domain to print the first time and blank the remaining times.

Comment: Thanks @hakre I will change that up once I figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in a comment, it's the DataTable-plugin that is (intentionally) messing up by sorting all rows by the value of the first column. Add an `"order": false` to the DataTable-options to disable the sort-ability.

```
$('#mx_report_table').DataTable({
    "scrollY":"400px",
    "scrollCollapse":true,
    "paging":true,
    "lengthMenu":[10,25,50,100],
    "pageLength":25,
    "order": false
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bep6uvfo/1/

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out when I'm back at my machine.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you so much. I'm gonna go read more jQuery docs for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, every domain has corresponding mx records

You could just loop and output the data to the table:

```
foreach($strings as $string => $mx) {
    echo "<tr>
              <td>$name</td>
              <td>$mx</td>
          </tr>";
}
```

The way you have your table simply with row after row looking the same, leaving a cell blank under the name column leaves the reader having to "presume" that in fact there's not a missing domain name but they should consider the previous one relates to multiple MX records.

I suggest separate sections with the header as the domain name and all corresponding MX records underneath each domain name heading.
Such as a blank row or whatever.

I would do away with looping on the db call, as all sorts of things could go wrong there too. And just fetch the data from the DB in an array, loop each domain name from the array with all that name's corresponding MX records, and have the name as the header row and then MX records in rows underneath, then the next name as header row and its MX records underneath.